# win server 2008 r2: scheduled task error

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a program that must be run as a scheduled task in fixed hours everyday.
The program must copy one or more xls files from one folder into another and then process them.
The program runs successfully when manually executed, but if launched as scheduled it exits with the following error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 
>   System.IO.**Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) (then a message in >italian that sounds like 'impossible to find a part of the path to the _**_file.xls') in >System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite) in >System.IO.FileInfo.CopyTo(String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)

The task I have created uses a user that has administrator access to every folder and complete control.
Where is the problem?
Thanx in advance
bitdiego

Answer (score 1):

When you run program with Task Scheduler it **locates** the files in System32 folder, because parent(Scheduler) is system program. So, try to provide absolute file path.

Also you can specify [Start](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/0e0913ac-753d-42eb-86b7-4bcf6e0df2e2/) In value, http://www.jargonsoft.com/support/knowledgebase.php?article=77

Comment: @bitdiego ok and are you using relative file path?

Comment: sorry, i made some mistakes...
first, i use the Microsoft Excel Interop library
the, i use absolute path: File.Copy(fToread, "F:\\XlsBadmTemp\\" + fileName, true); where fToread is like 'F:\folder\file.xls.
finally, xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(newfile, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true); 
where newfile is the copied and has an absolute path: F:\otherfolder\file.xls